# Concurrency solution in Swift for downloading data to database, notifying observers, and cancelling tasks?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, concurrency, realm

I have a bit of a conceptual question about concurrency in Swift for an iOS project (which uses Realm) that I'm building, but my understanding of stuff like GCD, Operations, and Notifications is lacking. I'd like the project to have the following functionality, but I'm unsure how to build it:

- My project has two main tabs: Library and Search
- Library holds objects (using Realm), Search allows you to search objects and add them to Library
- Search initially returns partial versions of objects. Upon clicking an object, the full version will start to load. If the user decides to save the object, before or after the full version is loaded, it will be saved to Realm and added to the library in its current form. If a full object finishes loading after a partial object is saved, it will be updated in the Library.
- If the full object is being loaded and the user navigates away from it in Search without saving, the task will be cancelled.

My Library objects are saved in Realm, and I was able to implement a rudimentary version of this with GCD async tasks that would save the full object if it had been loaded already, or save the partial object and begin a new async task that would later update it to the full version. However, this meant that I was often creating more tasks than necessary, and I was unable to cancel tasks that were no longer necessary.

I understand that Operations and OperationQueues can be cancelled, and would therefore probably be better than GCD. However, I'm not exactly sure how to properly add observers in my LibraryViewController and the object views so that they'll be updated when the full version is loaded. For example, should I be using Realm notifications for this? Or NSNotifications? Should I have a separate class that creates and performs these async operations, or should I do it within the Library/Search controllers? Should I create a cache-like Realm database that all objects are added to, updated once the full version is obtained, then moved over to the real database if they are saved? (not sure if that would even be possible)

Any high level help finding a solution to this would be much appreciated, and please let me know if more clarity on my issue is necessary. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest taking a look at FRP libraries like RxSwift or Combine from Apple. They offer a higher level and generic API compared to GCD, notifications, NSOperation and so on. You will end up writing less and better code but it will take some time to get used to it.

Comment: You DEFINITELY want to take advantage of realm notifications. Don't use NSNotifications they just aren't necessary when you're using realm. As for the rest of your questions it's hard to say. I'm not really sure what you mean by "loading an object" or how that might be done partially or fully.